# Git merge - trivial merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, conflict

If the base and the source have the same file content, and the destination branch/repo has some other file changes, which content does it keep, the source or the destination file?

To explain in detail

```
       A 
       | 
       B 
      / \
     C   D
```

Suppose that a file was added on the A->B edge, and then removed again in B->C, while it was left alone on the B->D edge.
We want to merge C and D.

If the common ancestor is A which doesn’t have the change (so A,C don’t have the file & B,D has the file) when merging C and D.

What happens if C (destination) merges from D?

What happens if D (destination) merges from C?

Comment: Sorry guys i think i didn't explain my question as intended, my bad...have reworded it..again...i have some doubts on that and hope you can help me clarify.

Comment: The common ancestor is B. But even if it was A, both streams (A-B-C and A-B-D) have the same new-file-insertion, so there is no problem. You must remember that git tracks changes, not before-and-after conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Merge is symmetric (aside from the fact that the merge ends up on one branch or the other). It will apply changes from both sides and report any conflicting changes it encounters in the process. In this case, since only one side has changes, the end result will look identical to the side that has the changes.

As an aside, you can try these operations quite safely to see what they will do; if things go pear-shaped, just [undo](https://wordpress.storelocatorplus.com/undoing-mistakes-easily-in-git/). Be sure to note the caveats at the bottom of the linked article, though.

Comment: Thanks :), but my bad i didn't verbalize my question as intended....have added more to my questions.

Comment: My answer still stands. See my comment to your amended question.

Comment: +1  But the link to the `undo` article is broken - do you have a alternative I can look at?

Comment: @5arx: I amended the link to what I think (I'm not 100% sure.) is the original article at a new site.

Comment: The link broke once again and now should point to https://wordpress.storelocatorplus.com/undoing-mistakes-easily-in-git/